i tried running pixi js but it gives me an error
I am new to pixi js but it won't start. I have watched tutorials and followed them but i keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'canvas')
    at get view (pixi.min.js:436:24397)
    at app.js:12:31


This is my html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Auto-moving Music Keys</title>
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

And my appjs:
var PIXI= PIXI || {};

const Application = PIXI.Application;

const app = new Application();

document.body.appendChild(app.view);


The <canvas> HTML element is used for drawing graphics with JavaScript, and Pixi.js uses it to render content. In Pixi.js, the view property of the Application class refers to this canvas, providing the visual surface on which Pixi.js renders. Without an initialized canvas, rendering won't occur.
Using var PIXI = PIXI || {}; could create an empty object if PIXI is undefined, overwriting the global namespace. In this case, const Application = PIXI.Application; fails (PIXI is now empty).
The Application class is part of the global PIXI object provided by the library.
Use this instead:
const app = new PIXI.Application({
    width: 800,  // Optional
    height: 600  // Optional
});

document.body.appendChild(app.view);

See also:

pixi.stage.width and pixi.stage.height take a scaling factor at the beginning, but take concrete pixel values on later usage
How to fit PIXI renderer into browser width and height?
https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/4731#issuecomment-370206929

